# Model visibility changing to 1/2 tone grey scale

Tags: objects, mirror

I am working with Mirror and Subsurface modifiers on a model. I completed the model and moved from edit to object mode. This is to position the model relative to other objects in the scene.
When I started the mesh and subsurface (in edit) displayed normally, easily visible as is the default.
After moving to object mode and positioning the model in the scene I now am seeing the model displaying in a half-tone, semi-transparent manner.
I know I have done something but have no idea what it was nor, of course, how to rectify the issue.

Comment: Can you show the problem? Yes, from your words it is approximately clear what kind of error you have, but it would be great to see it

Comment: Share the screenshot.